# Shortcode default attributes over-riding non-default attributes

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I have a shortcode with default attributes.  It works fine with the default attributes, but the user-entered attributes do not over-ride the default attributes.

Here is my shortcode code:

```
function wpa_success_stories_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'category' => 'success-stories',
        'maxposts' => '10',
    ), $atts )
);

/* print_r and echo to test values */
    print_r($atts);
echo $category;
echo $maxposts;

/* a bunch of stuff here to output code */

return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'success-stories', 'wpa_success_stories_shortcode' );
```

If the user inputs [success-stories category="news" maxposts="6"], then 'print_r($atts)' gives me `Array ( [0] => category="news" [1] => maxposts="6" )`, but `echo $category` returns `success-stories` and `echo $maxposts` returns `10`.  So how do I use the user-entered values in my code?

Comment: On further investigation, this is a child theme, and I think there is something in the parent theme that is messing with shortcodes....

Comment: I am using this in a child theme of the Oxygen theme, which is built on Hybrid core.  Might that be causing my problem?

Comment: It would be difficult for any code, plugin or theme, to mess with all shortcodes. Is this shortcode originally part of the parent theme?

Comment: Actually, upon even further investigation, it appears that this problem is caused by Advanced Custom Fields.  The shortcode works fine everywhere on the site except in an ACF WYSIWYG field.